# testing a directive's template function where attrs defined in link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How do you test an angularjs directive's template function's attributes where the attributes have both functions and angular binding values that are defined in the link function?
This is the directive.

```
var app = angular.module('mmApp', []);
app.directive('mmField', function(){

return {
    'restrict': 'E',
    'priority': 5,
    'replace': true,
    'scope': {
        'path': '@',
        'label': '@',
        'type': '@',
        'editable': '@'
    },
     //this is the template function and this is where labelText() does not evaluate at least not where I test it.
    'template': '<div class="mm-field">' +
        '<label for="{{inputId()}}" ng-show="labelText()">{{labelText()}}</label> ' +
        '</div>',

    'link': function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var query = null;
        //this is where the labelText() function is defined
        scope.labelText = function () {
            var labelAttrValue = (scope.label || attrs['withLabel'] || '');
            // cater for custom labels specified via the label or with-label attribute
            if (labelAttrValue && labelAttrValue.toLowerCase() !== 'true' && labelAttrValue.toLowerCase() !== 'false') {
                return (labelAttrValue || '') + ':';
            } else if (labelAttrValue.toLowerCase() !== 'false' && scope.field) {
                return (scope.field['name'] || 'FIELD_NAME_NOT_DEFINED') + ':';
            } else if (labelAttrValue.toLowerCase() == 'false') {
                return '';
            } else {
                return 'Loading...';
            }
        };
    }
])
```

This is where the directive is on a html page.

```
<mm-field with-label editable="false" path="{{rootPath}}.name"></mm-field>
```

I am using mocha and chai test suite. This is how I want to test it.

```
describe('InputId', function () {
    it.only('should generate an ID', function () {
        var element = $($compile('<mm-field with-label="MONKEY" editable="false"                                                                             path="something.name"></mm-field>' +
            '</div>')($scope));
        $scope.$digest();

        expect(element.find('label').attr('ng-show')).to.equal('an evaluated value of  labelText()');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide an example? Code, or jsfiddle etc. This will allow others to help you more easily.

Comment: By the way the solution works! I am asking how to test it as the attribute values do not update! Is it testable with the pattern used?